# HTML CSS prevent gap of span containers

Tags: css

I have made this little example which shows my problem. I have a few span containers and if two are in a column than the span container is a little bit longer than the one where only one span container is:

[My JS Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/q3jgytoq/)

```
<span class="times">
    <span class="timeType cursorPointer">
        <span>D</span>
        </span>
        <span>
            09:00 - 12:00
        </span>     
    </span>
    <span class="times">
        <span class="timeType cursorPointer">
            <span>N</span>
            </span>
            <span>
                14:00 - 17:00
            </span> 
        </span>
```

Does anyone know how to prevent this?
So this should be prevented:

[image]

Comment: So what to you want this to look like?

Comment: I think your assumption about the root cause may be wrong. The difference in width is because it's determined by the width of the *characters* in the text. Try using a fixed-width font to see what I mean.

Comment: @Jeroen I agree with you, but the space at the end of the string still present. You can view in this edited fiddle with monospaced font: https://jsfiddle.net/2xjm7ywq/1/

Comment: @UmerJaved Please don't post comments to draw attention to your answers it's not cool.

Comment: I have made changes to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can set a `min-width` to span, so whatever single character is in , `span` will be same size.

`Inline-block` is required to allow sizing.

```
.times {
  padding: 2px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
}

span span {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 1em;
}
```

Understand  that it comes from character used ...

Else you may use another font-family (**[W3C font-family: see monospace](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/fonts.en.html#font-family)** )where this will not happen, such as `courier`

***notice*** the use of `inline-block` to keep each box behave as a simple piece/wrapper in the flow.

```css
.times {
  padding: 2px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
.times {
  font-family: courier;
}
```

```html
<table class="weekTable">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span>
      <span class="times">
       <span class="timeType cursorPointer" ng-dblclick="vm.ScheduleIntervalContainerPropertiesModal(userScheduleManagementWeeksContainer, scheduleIntervalContainers, scheduleIntervalContainer)">
        <span>D</span>
        </span>
        <span>
        09:00 - 12:00
       </span>
        </span>
        <span class="times">
       <span class="timeType cursorPointer" ng-dblclick="vm.ScheduleIntervalContainerPropertiesModal(userScheduleManagementWeeksContainer, scheduleIntervalContainers, scheduleIntervalContainer)">
        <span>N</span>
        </span>
        <span>
        14:00 - 17:00
       </span>
        </span>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span>
      <span class="times">
       <span class="timeType cursorPointer" ng-dblclick="vm.ScheduleIntervalContainerPropertiesModal(userScheduleManagementWeeksContainer, scheduleIntervalContainers, scheduleIntervalContainer)">
        <span>M</span>
        </span>
        <span>
        09:00 - 12:00
       </span>
        </span>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q3jgytoq/4/

Answer (score 1):

```
.times {
    padding: 2px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Replace your css with this and it should work :)

And if you mean same width then you must determine the width of .times:

```
.times {
        padding: 2px;
        margin-left: 2px;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        color: #000;
        background-color: #fff;
        display: inline-block;
        min-width: 110px;
        text-align: center;
}
```

Replace this :)

Comment: That's the correct answer, but maybe you can explain a little to grow the upvotes and explain to OP why

Comment: No..it's not. It's due to the difference in character sizes.

Comment: Yes, but now they have equal paddings.

Comment: And that what the question was.

Comment: The point was to make then the same width and your answer does not do that.

Comment: The title says PREVENT GAP. There's nothing related to same width. Read the question again. Thank you

Comment: the gap comes from width used by **D** & **M** wich are different ... that's where the gap comes from and this might where it should be fixed ? your min-width won't work once one of those 2 might need more space

Comment: I understood that at first sight my friend. But his question didn't say this at all. His question was different

Comment: He just wanted to remove the gap at the right side. And display inline block does that perfectly.

Comment: so where the gap comes from ? ;) , this the meaning of our saying your min-width + a verdana font for instance at 16px http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLwRwj the same with a monospace font http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJaMwZ

Answer (score 0):

you can solve adding a fixed width to span and `display:inline-block`

```
 .times {
            padding: 2px;
            margin-left: 2px;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            color: #000;
            background-color: #fff;
            display: inline-block;
            width:120px

        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q3jgytoq/2/

Comment: **difference comes from the space used by letter D** and **then M** on the next line. setting a fixed width in px is not a good idea. if text change or font-size is increased it will break , you may use em. :)

Comment: it would if you used a monospace family-font without any width set ;) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGqLgJ

Comment: @GCyrillus setting a fixed width that's responsive to font is better ; but leaving those table cells to resize depending only on inner span is certainly what I would avoid ;)

Comment: there is a single cell on each row, i do not understand what you mean (table expand/shrinks on content and is block element unless reset to inline-table) ?  `.times` is a span here.

Comment: I mean that using a table structure like it's used in  OP markup doesn't make a lot of sense IMHO